# Java Servlet request.getRequestURL() logged abnormal string

Tags: networking, servlets

In one my servlet running in public domain, I got an abnormal string log from the request.getRequestURL() method. I keep logging the details and found an entry which is "http://answers.yahoo.com". Can some one help me in analyzing how this could have happened and also how to achieve it. Ideally the log should be the URL address in the browser using which a user or a device invokes the servlet.

For example if the registered name of the server mapped to the IP is http://www.alphabeta.com/x_serv?a=2, the logs should be alphabeta.com

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to log?

Use the method `getServerName()` from interface `javax.servlet.ServletRequest`  if you only need a host name. It returns the host name of the server to which the request was sent.

Use in conjunction with `getServerName()` and the method `getServletPath()` if you want to get the URL without any parameters on which was caused by your servlet. The method `getServletPath()` from interface `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` returns the part of this request's URL that calls the servlet but does not include any extra path information or a query string.

And the following code fragment will determine your page's absolute URL:

```
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
if (request.getQueryString() != null) {
   uri += '?' + request.getQueryString();
}
URL reconstructedUrl = new URL(request.getScheme(),
                           request.getServerName(),
                           request.getServerPort(),
                           uri);
logger.info("The full URL: " + reconstructedUrl.toString());
```

Where `URL` class is from the package `java.net`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how can the request url be spoofed, which seems to be what happened here

Comment: What you don't like my solution to this issue?

Comment: You asked "What exactly do you want?" - I thought the OP wanted to know how is it possible to spoof the URL returned from getRequestURL. I was just trying to help. Please ignore my comment.

Comment: Thanks so much Andrey for providing the details.Thanks Disco for highlighting the spoofing issue. As Disco mentioned about URl spoofing, I am also interested in knowing how the spoofing had happened. Please provide me some details in this regard.